# How to differentiate the lock and start button pressed in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to differentiate the below scenarios:

1. Press Lock, then unlock button  and open the application
2. Press windows button and search for application from list of apps and open it

I need to handle the scenarios differently, how exactly can we differentiate above scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way for Silverlight-based apps to [detect the lockscreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured(v=vs.105).aspx), but what about all the other ways you could lose foreground status - launching the camera, following a toast, opening a reminder, multitasking with back button, etc?